# How to find the error line in HTML when HTMLParserError occurs

Tags: python, html-parser

now i am writing a web crawler using python, but sometimes it throws HTMLParserError:

`junk characters in start tag: u'\u201dTPL_password_1\u201d\r\n\t\t', at line 21285, column 6`

it said the error was found at line 21285, does it mean that the error is found at line 21285 in the HTML source code? if not, how can i know what is the current HTML code that generates error? and what is the current parsing url?

my parse class can be simplified as follows:

```
class ParsePage(HTMLParser):

    """Parse the given page content using HTMLParser"""

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):

        #Here i tried to add `try...expect` to inspect the current tag and attrs, but it seems python didnt enter the except at all, why? the error message said the error was found at start tag, why it didnt enter the except at all?

        try:
            Some codes doing with the start tag...
        except HTMLParser.HTMLParseError, e:
            print "e: ", e, '\n' 
            print 'tag: ', tag, '\n'
            print 'attrs: ', atts, '\n'
            exit(1) 

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        #Some codes doing with end tags...



geturl = ParsePage()

#Here i can catch the HTMLParseError if i add `try...except` in the following line, but i dont know how to get the useful information here when i catch the exception    
geturl.feed(cur_page)
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**how can i know what is the current HTML code that generates error?**

> junk characters in start tag: u'\u201dTPL_password_1\u201d\r\n\t\t',
>   at line 21285, column 6

html line number 21285 in current HTML page

**and what is the current parsing url?**

what link do you parse?

> geturl.feed(cur_page)

cur_page is your current page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it told you the line the error was found in. What else do you need?

Also, what does the URL have to do with this? You pass your HTML page as a string to `feed` - `HTMLParser` has no idea where it came from.